# Aggregate data.table with weights in R

Tags: r, data.table, frequency, tapply

I am new using data.table, and it is sometimes confusing. 
I have a dataset that looks like this (data.table)

```
GEO    ANC   WG  V1  ....
P1      A1  w1  v11 ....
P1      A2  w2  v12 ....
P2      A1  w3  v13 ....
P3      A1  w4  v14 ....
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(GEO = c("b","b","b","b","b","a","a","c"),
                 ANC = c("x","y","z","x","x",NA, "x","w"), 
                 WG=sample(100,8), 
                 c=sample(5,8, replace=T))
```

The variable `WG` gives the weight of each observation.

I want to compute the weighted frequency of `AN` by each location `GEO`, in the **fastest possible way** and that gives an output that I can then **easily merge with my data** (hence I am not using `tapply`). What I have done so far is:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(n){wpct(n,dt[["WG"]],na.rm=T)}),
                             by=c("GEO"),.SDcols=c("AN")]
```

It seems to work fine, but the output gives only two columns: `GEO` and `AN`, and the frequency is under the variable `AN`. Something like

```
GEO    AN   
P1      fre1  
P1      fre2  
P2      fre3
P3      fre4
```

I would prefer an output with three columns: `GEO`, `AN` (with the real values `A1`, `A2`, and so forth), and a third column with the frequencies. 
Like that I'll easily merge this data with the original one.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: To assign the result to a new column, use syntax like `dt[,freq:=wpct(AN,WG,na.rm=TRUE),by=GEO]` There is no need for .SDcols or shenanigans with `[[`. I suggest you go through some of the tutorials/vignettes: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @Frank: when I use your syntax with the reproducible example, I get the error: `Supplied 3 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 5 in column 'freq' (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items)`. I get the same error with my real data.

Comment: BTW, what is `wpct`?

Comment: @akrun: a function to produce weighted frequencies: [wpct](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/weights/docs/wpct)

Comment: Why not just `DT[, wpct(ANC, WG, na.rm = TRUE), by = GEO]`? What is the point of `lapply`, `.SD`, `function` or `.SDcols`? The main speed limit here the efficiency of the `wpct` function itself.

Comment: Oh I see Frank already posted that. The reason for the warning is because the result is smaller than the size of your data. The problem is not with `data.table`, rather with you trying to do something unreasonable.

Comment: @Doon_Bogan I just meant to illustrate how data.table syntax works, which is quite different from how you were writing. (That's why I said "syntax like". I wasn't sure that you were trying to make a new column, nor how `wpct` works.)

Comment: Perhaps `na.omit( DT[ , list(ANC=unique(ANC), wpct(ANC, WG, na.rm=TRUE)), by=GEO])` , a modification of Frank's code.

Comment: @akrun: works like a charm, thanks!!!! The `list(unique(`... does the trick